# How can I access Production DB securely without static ip

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I am running a small scale app on AWS EC2 and it has PostgreSQL installed on it.

I want to access this production DB remotely but also want to keep it secure and I'm not sure if what I am doing is enough.

When working on company projects, I simply whitelisted company's static ip and block all else but in this case, I cannot use a static IP and my ip changes quite often.

So far, I have

- Changed default port for DB
- setup cloudflare (Show challenge for countries that I don't access the service from)
- made password using random password generator

but I feel like I could do much more and because my DB contains some sensitive personal information feel like I SHOULD do more.

What else can I do to further secure my DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql via SSH Tunnel

```
ssh -L 5432:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

And connect to 127.0.0.1 localy:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1
```

On the server you can disable all listening ports for postgresql and leave only the ssh port open.

Also ensure the SSH isn't available for password access, only ssh key access.

Comment: Can i use pgadmin with this method? not just the cli?

Comment: I suspect it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be secure is to use a VPN client.

Inside the VPN client profile you can select what port can be open.

That way the server is never on the internet and your traffic to it is encrypted inside the tunnel.